# How does the solution of a differential equation on a manifold yield a map?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

1. In: "**A solution $x^μ(λ)$ is a map from $\mathbb{R} → M$**": Why is $x^μ(λ)$  considered a *map* and why does it go from $\mathbb{R} → M$? I can't seem to illustrate this in my mind.
2. In:"If the manifold is $\mathbb{R}^D$, then we know that the vector $dx^μ/dλ$ is tangent to the curve $x^μ(λ)$". What if the manifold is a general manifold, what happens to the tangent?

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing is that the solution is a curve on the manifold $M$. Remember that a manifold looks locally like $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then locally you can interpret the differential equation as telling you the velocity of some point particle as a function of position in Euclidean space (think of a particle flowing through a river that has a well-defined velocity at each point). The parameter $\lambda$ is $\mathbb{R}$-valued (think of it like a time), and to each value of $\lambda$ is associated a point on the manifold $x^\mu(\lambda)$. That's all that is meant by a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $M$.

If the manifold happens not to be $\mathbb{R}^n$, $V^\mu(x)$ is still tangent to the curve at each point - remember that locally the manifold looks like $\mathbb{R}^n$, so this is meaningful in the same sense as in Euclidean space. Actually you can probably illustrate this very well in your head - after all, we're always walking around on the surface of a sphere, a manifold that is not $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, very informative, I have a couple of questions: 1- You're saying that the parameter $\lambda$ is $\mathbb{R}$-valued. (Is $\lambda$ on the manifold or is it mapped from the local coordinates?) 2- "To each value of $\lambda$ is associated a point on the manifold $x^{\mu}$, did you mean instead to each value of $\lambda$ is associated a curve on the manifold $M$? I'm confused a little because the author there says:"There is an integral curve through every point of any open subset of $M$ in which the vector field does not vanish. "

Comment: $\lambda$ itself just takes values in $\mathbb{R}$. One thing that might be confusing you is that in order to assign a point on the manifold to each value of $\lambda$, you need an initial condition - "at $\lambda=0$, $x(0)=x_0$" - just like solving any other first order differential equation.

Comment: For your second question, no, $\lambda$ parametrizes a single curve. Again, think of this in terms of initial conditions. You have a velocity field $V^\mu(x)$, and can drop a particle into this field at time $\lambda=0$. The curve on the manifold is just the trajectory traced out by the particle. You can choose to drop the particle anywhere on the manifold, so there's an integral curve through every point (though not necessarily distinct curves).